# recyclerview problem when scrooling right half screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When scrolling from left half screen of the mobile scrolling is happening but when i scroll from right half screen scroling is not happening.

This is my xml clode.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/postRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

My Java code is

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        binding.postRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.postRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)
enter code here
```

Comment: Are you sure, you don't have some other view over your recyclerView? You should share your whole layout.

Comment: Hi Praveen, i have added my java code also. Please check now.

Comment: I meant your XML layout file, post that.

Comment: You don't need to set `layoutManager` orientation to `vertical` manually, as its default orientation is already `vertical`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after so much search i found the solution. Actually i have used Floating button in that page due to that hieght from right side scrolling was not happend in Recyclerview.